# UWP changing ResourceDictionary programmatically

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10

I am designing an app that retrieves colors from a REST API and needs to use these to theme the app. I am trying to define the colors inside of styles in my ResourceDictionary since one of the colors I need to set is the PointerOver VisualState of a button. I am currently using the below method to change the SolidColorBrushes.

```
App.Current.Resources["PrimaryBrush"] = myNewSolidColorBrush;
```

When I bind my element's background directly to this StaticResurce the colors work perfectly. But, when I move this inside of a style into my separate file with a ResourceDictionary and bind the background inside the style to the to that SolidColorBrush resource that I am changing.

My problem is that when I change the SolidColorBrush programmatically, the binding in my style does not update! Is there a way to either force the resource dictionary to revaluate its bindings or programmatically change the setter values in my defined style?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to force a fetch using styles but you can bind the colors in the style to a static property in App.xaml.cs of type SolidColourBrush and use `{x:static propertyName}` to bind it. And then just keep raising propertyChanged.

Comment: That's an interesting idea! I will try that. Can you just access those values then globally with `App.*`?

Comment: If they are static then yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My problem is that when I change the SolidColorBrush programmatically, the binding in my style does not update!

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryBrush" Color="Yellow"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The problem is that you have assigned the new `myNewSolidColorBrush` object to `PrimaryBrush`, and the [`StaticResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/staticresource-markup-extension) doesn't support dynamic change. For you requirement you could modify the property of the `PrimaryBrush` object.

```
(App.Current.Resources["PrimaryBrush"]as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.Red;
```